# awk to match two fields in two files

Tags: awk, comparison, matching

I want to find lines where fields 1 and 2 from file1 match fields 2 and 3 from file2, and then print all fields from file2. There are more lines in file2 than in file1

File1

```
rs116801199 720381 
rs138295790 16057310
rs131531 16870251
rs131546 16872281
rs140375 16873251
rs131552 16873461
```

File2

```
--- rs116801199 720381 0.026 0.939 0.996 0 -1 -1 -1                                                                            
1 rs12565286 721290 0.028 1.000 1.000 2 0.370 0.934 0.000                                                                      
1 rs3094315 752566 0.432 1.000 1.000 2 0.678 0.671 0.435                                                                       
--- rs3131972 752721 0.353 0.906 0.938 0 -1 -1 -1                                                                              
--- rs61770173 753405 0.481 0.921 0.950 0 -1 -1 -1
```

I tried something like:

```
awk -F 'FNR==NR{a[$1];b[$2];next} FNR==1 || ($2 in a && $3 in b)' file1 file2 > test
```

But got a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
awk -F 'FNR==NR{a[$1];b[$2];next} FNR==1 || ($2 in a && $3 in b)' file1 file2
```

The option `-F` expects an argument but no argument is provided intentionally.  The result is that `awk` interprets the entirety of the code as the field separator.  That is why that code does not run as expected.

From the problem statement, I didn't see why `FNR==1` should be in the code.  So, I removed it.  Once that is done, the parens are unnecessary.  If that is the case, then, the code further simplifies to:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];b[$2];next} $2 in a && $3 in b' file1 file2 
--- rs116801199 720381 0.026 0.939 0.996 0 -1 -1 -1
```